# Why do we declare the inputs of our design as reg in testbench and outputs as wire?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vlsi, testbench

Why do we declare the **inputs** of our design as **reg** in testbench and **outputs** as **wire**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shashank's answer is good.

I would like to add that in a more sophisticated testbench, all DUT pin signals could be declared as wires since you might choose to have another module drive your DUT inputs (i.e., a bus-functional model).

If all of your stimulus is driven from the testbench directly, then it makes sense to declare DUT input signals as reg (or logic) in the testbench module.

Comment: **DUT** Pin signals declared as wire? Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have used the term "pin".  I meant all of the nets attached to ports on the DUT could be declared as wires in the case where the DUT inputs are driven by another structural model instantiated in the testbench. (as opposed to driving them from behavioral code in the testbench).

Answer (score 5):

Inputs are declared as `reg` and outputs as `wire` only in Verilog. In SystemVerilog, we use `logic` for 4-state simulation and `bit` for 2-state simulation.

In Verilog, inputs are declared as `reg` because they are variables which store values during simulation. The value is stored in the inputs of type `reg` till it is overwritten by some other value.

The datatype `wire` is used for outputs because outputs in the testbench are driven by the DUT (Device Under Test) **continuously**, and they don't store any value during simulation.

In SystemVerilog, declare a signal as `wire` only if you expect it to have multiple drivers.

Further reading: [Mr. Dave Rich's excellent blog on wire and reg on Siemens Blogs](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/)